# Double check my IF AND OR statement

Tags: php

is this logical... If $dirchk1 and $dirchk2 exist or if just $dirchk1 exist continue processing. But if only $dirchk2 exist then process else statement. Thanks in advance

```
$dirchk1 = "/temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc";
$dirchk2 = "/temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc"; 
    if (is_file($dirchk1) && is_file($dirchk2)) || (is_file($dirchk1)) {
//.. do code 
    } else {
    ...// only $dirchk2 exist
    }
```

**EDIT: sorry I failed to mention that if $dirchk1 and $dirchk2 DO NOT exist then the else statement should process.**

Comment: Huh? So: yes+yes = if, yes+no = if, no+yes = else, no+no = else? So there's actually no dependency on $dirchk2 at all? It's always the 'if' case if $dirchk1 exists and always the 'else' case if it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't matter whether or not `$dirchk2` exists then just pull it from the condition.

```
    if (is_file($dirchk1)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. You want to execute `//.. do code` as long as `$dirchk1` exists, and otherwise execute the else if `$dirchk2` exists, so:

```
if (is_file($dirchk1)) {
    //.. do code 
} elseif (is_file($dirchk2)) {
    // only $dirchk2 exist
}
```

Comment: i want to execute //.. do code only if $dirchk1 and $dirchk2 exit together or of $dirchk1 exist alone. if $dirchk2 is by itself then do the else code

Comment: Following OP's edit above, my elseif should be replaced with a simple else.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think that's right. There's no check for dirchk2 on the else case, and your if case is `($1 && $2) || $1` would reorder into `$1 && ($2 || true)` == `$1` with no $2 check. You probably want

```
if (is_file($dirchk1)) {
    //.. do code 
} elseif (is_file($dirchk2)) {
    // only $dirchk2 exist
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on your elseif, otherwise I think the code is identical to my solution! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` will execute even of both of them does not exist and your `if` does not check the second condition. So, do it like this:

```
 if (is_file($dirchk1) && is_file($dirchk2)) || (is_file($dirchk1) && !is_file($dirchk2))
 {
     //.. do code 
 }
 elseif((is_file($dirchk2))
 {
    ...// only $dirchk2 exist
 }
```

Comment: you can simplify the if statement to `is_file($dirchk1)`; think about it.

Answer (score 2):

"Is this logical?"
I believe the answer is no.

```
let p = is_file($dirchk1)
let q = is_file($dirchk2)

  |p |p'|
--+--+--+
q |1 |0 |
--+--+--+
q'|1 |0 |
```

You want to do the code when only p is true, and then else if only q is true, so the simplification is as follows:

```
if (is_file($dirchk1))
{
  //do code
}
else if (is_file($dirchk2))
{
  //only $dirchk2 exists
}
```

EDIT: After the OP specified the false/false condition needing to be part of the else block:

the final answer should be:

```
if (is_file($dirchk1))
{
  //do code
}
else
{
  //dirchk2 may or may not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention: *But if only $dirchk2 exist then process else statement.*

Which translates to following TT:

```
$dirchk1   $dirchk2   process?

true       true       if-block
true       false      if-block
false      false      if-block
false      true       else-block
```

which translates to:

```
if( ($dirchk1 && $dirchk2) || (!$dirchk2) ) {
  // if block
} else {
  // else block
}
```

Or you could also do :

```
if(! (!$dirchk1 && $dirchk2) ) {
  // if block
} else {
  // else block
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a truth table. (Although I think you meant to use `$dirchk2` for the middle column.)

Comment: @zzzzBov: The OP said " If $dirchk1 and $dirchk2 exist or if just $dirchk1 exist continue processing. **But if only $dirchk2 exist then process else statement** " The table is correct.

Comment: @In silico then read my answer and understand why you're wrong. I'm not going to repeat myself in a comment.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Read again. If **only** $dirchk2 exist then process else statement. The key word is **only**. Of course, the OP may be underspecifying the requirements, but the table codaddict makes sense since that's what the OP mentioned.

Comment: the else statement cant be executed if `is_file($dirchk1)` returns true, and then only **if** `is_file($dirchk2)` returns true, which means that **only** `$dirchk2` exists in that case. You seriously need to stop and think about this.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I didn't say you were wrong. Nowhere did I say that your answer was wrong. All I said is that your claim that codaddict was wrong is not accurate, at least based on the OP's stated requirements.

Comment: false false and false true need to go to the else-block. Thanks for the diagram i forgot to consider both not being there

Comment: wrong: false false does not go to the if block. that's why you're all wrong.

Comment: @zzzzBov: It was "wrong" because the OP failed to mention that the "false/false" condition had to go into the else block. It was the OP's fault for underspecifying the requirements - don't be surprised if someone might get it wrong based on lack of information.

Comment: it was wrong before the OP mentioned the false/false condition, i'm going to append something to my answer.

Comment: @zzzzBov: It may not be what the OP wanted exactly but you can't say that we're "all wrong" based on requirements that was not adequately explained in the first place. This answer was helpful because codaddict actually bothered to draw out the entire truth table, allowing the OP to realize that the false/false case was not accounted for.

Comment: @In silico, If you would take the time to think about the OP's original requirements, he never specified the false/false condition as being part of the `if-else` block, so you **cant** assume that it is part of the `if-else` block. You're assumption turned out to be wrong,your answer misleading, and your comments aggressive.

Comment: @zzzzBov: So you assumed that the false/false condition had to go into the else block? Nowhere did the OP said that the false/false condition needed to go into the if *or* else block. That's what I meant by underspecified information.

Comment: @In silico you sound like you haven't bothered to even read my answer. As the false-false condition wasn't mentioned, i left it as a state that would enter **neither** the if block **nor** the else block. With the OP's clarification, (that the false-false condition should enter the else block), I made an edit to my answer that allows the false-false condition to enter the else block.

Comment: @zzzzBov: First of all, I did not downvote your answer. I didn't vote either way because of the fact that the OP's question needed clarification. Again, I never said that your answer was wrong. I simply objected to you saying that somebody was flat out wrong simply because the OP was not clear enough in their question.

Comment: so its safe to say something like this if (is_file($dirchk1) && is_file($dirchk2)) || (!is_file($dirchk1)) { would work? and send $dirchk2 being alone or both $dirchk1 and $dirchk2 not existing at all?

Comment: @In silico you're certainly entitled to object.

Comment: @acctman Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has a correct answer. I have an explanation in my post. Try not to over-complicate things.